# Can increasing dimentionality improve classification in Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, dimensionality-reduction, accuracy, interpolation

I had a dataset where each data sample (pixel) had 7 features (reflectance at 7 wavelengths). However, running my neural network on the 7 features was not able to reach a high accuracy in classifying the pixels into two groups.
Somehow, I came up with this idea of interpolating over the 7 wavelengths so that I got 70 features (reflectance values now at 70 wavelengths) for each pixel. This obviously led to an increase in the data volume, but I found the neural network performed much better with this modification, with significantly fewer misclassifications. So far, I was under the impression that dimensionality reduction helps in machine learning, but in this case the results seems to suggest otherwise. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: When you mention the performance of the neural network, how was the model evaluated? If you are evaluating it using the same training data and you increase the dimensionality, the model will overfit easier because the weight matrix increases (at least for the first layer if the architecture is static), so the training accuracy is higher. Check with a validation subset as well during the training process in case you are not doing it.

Comment: "dimensionality reduction helps in machine learning" is usually true when it helps to avoid the overfitting of the model - which usually implies reducing the accuracy for the training subset but increasing it for the validation data.

Comment: @RobertoT I am evaluating based on the confusion matrix from the Test data. There I see very few misclassifications...

Comment: More data is generally better than less data.